# A nested parenthesis parsing case leading multiple sequence results

Tags: pyparsing

I'd like to parse a string with nested parenthesis with these conditions:

- Elements are delimited by comma `,` or bar `|`.
- Nested parenthesis elements might be a single alphanum or another nested parenthesis.
- Each nested parenthesis element connected by bar `|` literal leads to creation of a new sequence combining previous sequence elements and forward elements connected by comma`,` outside that nested parenthesis.

In order to clarify, let me give some examples of input strings and the results they should return:

`(a, b, c)` should return: `a, b, c`

`(a, (b | c))` should return: `a, b` and `a, c`

`(a, b, (c | (d, e)), f)` should return: `a, b, c, f` and `a, b, d, e, f`

`(a, b, (c | (d, e) | f), g)` should return: `a, b, c, g` and `a, b, d, e, g` and `a, b, f, g`

`(a, b, c, ((d, (e | f)) | (g, h)), i)` should return: `a, b, c, d, e, i` and `a, b, c, d, f, i` and `a, b, c, g, h, i`

`((a | b), c)` should return: `a, c` and `b, c`

Comment: If you look at ',' and '|' as operators, you should be able to parse this in very short order with the `infixNotation` method. Once parsed, you'll then need to recursively process the results to generate all the various combinations of paths through these terms. See how this is done in the invRegex example on the pyparsing wiki.

Comment: I did know this method exists. Thanks for the reply ;) Looking into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(from the pyparsing wiki)
You can get the string parsed using `infixNotation` (formerly known as `operatorPrecedence`). Assuming that ',' has precedence over '|', this would look like:

```
variable = oneOf(list(alphas.lower()))
expr = infixNotation(variable, 
            [
            (',', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
            ('|', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
            ])
```

Converting your test cases to a little testing framework, we can at least test the parsing part:

```
tests = [
    ("(a, b, c)", ["abc"]),
    ("(a, b | c)", ["ab", "c"]),
    ("((a, b) | c)", ["ab", "c"]),
    ("(a, (b | c))", ["ab", "ac"]),
    ("(a, b, (c | (d, e)), f)", ["abcf","abdef"]),
    ("(a, b, (c | (d, e) | f), g)", ["abcg", "abdeg", "abfg"]),
    ("(a, b, c, ((d, (e | f)) | (g, h)), i)",
      ["abcdei", "abcdfi", "abcghi"]),
    ("((a | b), c)", ["ac", "bc"]),
    ]

for test,expected in tests:
    # if your expected values *must* be lists and not strings, then
    # add this line
    # expected = [list(ex) for ex in expected]
    result = expr.parseString(test)
    print result[0].asList()
```

which will give you something like this:

```
['a', ',', 'b', ',', 'c']
[['a', ',', 'b'], '|', 'c']
[['a', ',', 'b'], '|', 'c']
['a', ',', ['b', '|', 'c']]
['a', ',', 'b', ',', ['c', '|', ['d', ',', 'e']], ',', 'f']
['a', ',', 'b', ',', ['c', '|', ['d', ',', 'e'], '|', 'f'], ',', 'g']
['a', ',', 'b', ',', 'c', ',', [['d', ',', ['e', '|', 'f']], '|', ['g', ',', 'h']], ',', 'i']
[['a', '|', 'b'], ',', 'c']
```

That is the easy part, parsing the string and getting the operator precedence reflected in the resulting structure. Now if you follow the example from the regex inverter, you will need to attach objects to each parsed bit, something like this:

```
class ParsedItem(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens[0]
class Var(ParsedItem): 
    """ TBD """
class BinaryOpn(ParsedItem):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens[0][::2]
class Sequence(BinaryOpn):
    """ TBD """
class Alternation(BinaryOpn):
    """ TBD """

variable = oneOf(list(alphas.lower())).setParseAction(Var)
expr = infixNotation(variable, 
            [
            (',', 2, opAssoc.LEFT, Sequence),
            ('|', 2, opAssoc.LEFT, Alternation),
            ])
```

Now you will have to implement the bodies of `Var`, `Sequence`, and `Alternation`. You will not get a list of values directly back from pyparsing, instead you will get one of these object types back. Then, instead of calling `asList()` as I did in the sample above, you'll call something like `generate` or `makeGenerator` to get a generator from that object. Then you'll invoke that generator to have the objects generate all the different results for you.

I leave the rest as an exercise for you.

-- Paul